# Ms Access - project management with employee timesheet

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a solution which will help to track how projects are performing in the sense of spent hours. I have few tables: Employees, Projects, Calendar. I need to open a form which will list all the dates for specific month from a calendar for specific employee at one view. I.e. I have combo box on the top which will search for employee and month for which I want to enter the data. Then next to each date I will be able to assign hours worked per day and assign the project. How to accomplish that? I searched how it can be done but I am stuck. I created cross join table: Calendar with Employees (who are active based on start and end date) but I do not know if this is a good approach and what I should do with this query.

Comment: You say you created a cross join table but then you say it is a query. You need a junction table, not a query, for input of employee work time. Google "access template database attendance".

Comment: Then if you want to batch create a month's worth of records for each employee, that is another issue.

Comment: It sounds like you want a form for batch creating records.  Here is a link for the last time I answered that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175837/populating-multiple-fields-in-subform-using-combobox-and-afterupdate-event-prodc/70184495#70184495